# Not able to delete Rows from Sqlitedatabase after some time intervel

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am new to SQLite in android.I tried my best to get the solution to Question but it seems to bit difficult for me.

```
private LocalStorageHandler localstoragehandler;
localstoragehandler = new LocalStorageHandler(this);

    Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                localstoragehandler.deleteAll();
                localstoragehandler.close();
            }
        }, 20000);





 public void deleteAll() {
            db.execSQL("TRUNCATE table" + TABLE_NAME_MESSAGES);
            db.close();
        }
```

I am getting below mention error.any help or criticism is welcome.Thank you in advance.

```
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TRUNCATE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: TRUNCATE tableandroidim_messages
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at at.vcity.androidim.tools.LocalStorageHandler.deleteAll(LocalStorageHandler.java:92)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at at.vcity.androidim.Messaging$5.run(Messaging.java:253)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4812)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
01-20 15:22:37.477: E/AndroidRuntime(3243):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

    01-20 14:58:35.148: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    01-20 14:58:35.148: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are you sure you are passing right table name because according to your log you are passing your database not table

Comment: `db.delete()` is a method to delete a table, not a database. You really do not want this line.

Comment: i want to delete all row from my table.

Comment: Your logcat clearly says that there is syntax error near TRUNCATE.

Comment: what is error @PiyushGupta

Comment: Its a syntax error. Like "," or any other parenthesis so just try to look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `TRUNCATE` in sqlite. (Even if there was, you'd need a space between the keyword `table` and the table name.)

Use `"DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME_MESSAGES` instead to delete all rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're deleting the entire database with `db.delete(DATABASE_NAME, null, null);` before you're executing the SQL statements to delete the data. You might want to re-evaluate what you're trying to achieve - an entire data wipe, or destruction of the database itself?

Comment: I want to delete all row in that table

Answer (score -1):

The complete syntax is: "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME_MESSAGES+";";